# React Native - Connecting Two RNCPickerSelect's from 'react-native-picker-select'

Tags: react-native, picker

How do I change the 'items' from a 'RNCPickerSelect' when I've selected a value from another 'RNCPickerSelect'?

For example, when I select a value called 'brand' from a **RNCPickerSelect**, the *other* **RNCPickerSelect** displays the 'models' associated with that specific 'brandName'. Basically, I want the 'items' from the *other* **RNCPickerSelect** to be influenced by the first **RNCPickerSelect**.

Here's the code:

```
================================Brands===================================
<RNPickerSelect
            pickerProps={{ style: {overflow: 'hidden' } }}
            onValueChange={(value) => console.log(value)}
            placeholder={brandplaceholder}
  //           style={styles.dropbox}
            items={[
            { label: 'brand1', value: 'brand1' },
            { label: 'brand2', value: 'brand2' },
            { label: 'brand3', value: 'brand3' },
            ]}
            onValueChange={(val) => setBrand(val)}
          />
==========================================================================

=================================Models===================================
<RNPickerSelect
            pickerProps={{ style: {overflow: 'hidden' } }}
            onValueChange={(value) => console.log(value)}
            placeholder={brandplaceholder}
  //           style={styles.dropbox}
            items={[
            { label: 'model1', value: 'model1' },
            { label: 'model2', value: 'model2' },
            { label: 'model3', value: 'model3' },
            ]}
            onValueChange={(val) => setModel(val)}
          />
==========================================================================

===============================Model Ideas================================
            items={[
            { label: 'model4', value: 'model4' },
            { label: 'model5', value: 'model5' },
            { label: 'model6', value: 'model6' },
            ]}
                            **and**
            items={[
            { label: 'model7', value: 'model7' },
            { label: 'model8', value: 'model8' },
            { label: 'model9', value: 'model9' },
            ]}
==========================================================================
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that with a simple state logic. When the first picker selects, it will update the other picker's predefined items array.

```
import React from "react";
import RNPickerSelect from 'react-native-picker-select';

const firstPick = [
                { label: 'Football', value: 'football' },
                { label: 'Baseball', value: 'baseball' },
                { label: 'Hockey', value: 'hockey' },
            ]

const secondPick = [[
                { label: 'Football2', value: 'football2' },
                { label: 'Baseball2', value: 'baseball2' },
                { label: 'Hockey2', value: 'hockey2' },
            ]

export const Dropdown = () => {
    
   const [dynamicPickerArr, setDynamicPickerArr] = useState(firstPick)

    return (
        <RNPickerSelect
            onValueChange={(value) => {
                 // Magic here
                 // Your changed value logic should be here
                 setDynamicPickerArr(secondPick)}
             }
            items={[
                { label: 'Football', value: 'football' },
                { label: 'Baseball', value: 'baseball' },
                { label: 'Hockey', value: 'hockey' },
            ]}
        />
         <RNPickerSelect
            onValueChange={(value) => console.log(value)}
            items={}
        />
    );
};
```

Comment: Ignore my last question, I've figured out how! Thanks a bunch! One more question, how do I implement multiple values on the 'onValueChange'? For example, when I pick the value 'Football' from the first 'RNCPickerSelect', I would like the other one to display the items from 'firstPick', and 'Baseball' for the 'secondPick', and so on. Again, thanks a bunch for responding and helping out!

Answer (score 1):

With the codes provided by @FreakyCoder, I've successfully fixed and improved the 'RNCPickerSelect'. I have adjusted the code to fit my project and have added some extra lines of codes as well. Thanks again @FreakyCoder!

The Sample Codes:

```
export default function MainPage() {
//===============Example Selections===============//
  const firstPick = [
    { label: 'Football', value: 'football' },
    { label: 'Baseball', value: 'baseball' },
    { label: 'Hockey', value: 'hockey' },
  ];

  const secondPick = [
    { label: 'Football2', value: 'football2' },
    { label: 'Baseball2', value: 'baseball2' },
    { label: 'Hockey2', value: 'hockey2' },
  ];

  const thirdPick = [
    { label: 'Football3', value: 'football3' },
    { label: 'Baseball3', value: 'baseball3' },
    { label: 'Hockey3', value: 'hockey3' },
  ];
//================================================//

  const [dynamicPickerArr, setDynamicPickerArr] = useState(HondaModel)

  return(
    <RNPickerSelect
        onValueChange={(value) =>  { setModel(value)

        // Magic here
        // Your changed value logic should be here

        if(value=='football') 
        return Football=setDynamicPickerArr(thirdPick)

        else if(value=='baseball')
        return Baseball=setDynamicPickerArr(secondPick)

        else if(value=='hockey')
        return Baseball=setDynamicPickerArr(firstPick)
   }
              
    }
        items={[
        { label: 'Football', value: 'football' },
        { label: 'Baseball', value: 'baseball' },
        { label: 'Hockey', value: 'hockey' },
        ]}
  />

  <RNPickerSelect
      onValueChange={(value) => console.log(value)}
      items={dynamicPickerArr}
  />

 )

}
```